# How to upload a 360degree image on PDP page in Hybris

Tags: iframe, sap-commerce-cloud

To embed a 360-degree image inside a webpage, it needs to be embedded using iframe/script tag.

This requires customization to render it on pdp, as there is nothing inside Media object (backoffice) to hold an iframe.

Anyway, is it possible to upload a 360deg image in hybris and use it in the PDP along with the image galleries?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom component for 3D images in store front. Then you can remove add it to product page with impex or backoffice.
Also you can create custom editor for backoffice. You can use media service for storing 3D image urls or files.